# How to get the Time value from datetime picker

Tags: c#, datetime, stored-procedures, datetimepicker

How to get the time value in a stored procedure from a `DateTimePicker` value?

For Example: 
I have a datetime picker value stored into my table as:

```
'2010-04-06 09:00:00.000' 
'2010-04-07 14:30:00.000'
```

- I have to get the date seperately using `Convert(varchar,Date,3) as Date`
- I have got the time seperately using `Convert(time,Time)`

But it  show the values as 9:00 or 14:30

I need it to show them as 9:00AM and 2:30PM instead of 14:30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yourDate.ToString("t");`. 
Also check [other formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try something like that:

```
date.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get current time you can use

```
now.toshorttime()
```